# ASMX webservice - return JSON instead of XML

Tags: c#, json, web-services, asmx, javascriptserializer

I have a web service that contains one method:

```
[WebMethod]
public string Movies()
{
    using (var dataContext = new MovieCollectionDataContext())
    {
        var query = dataContext.Movies.Select(m =>new{m.Title,m.ReleaseDate}).Take(20);
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(query);
    }
}
```

The method properly serializes the object, but when I view the response in FireBug, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{"Title":"SQL","ReleaseDate":"\/Date(1224007200000)\/"},{"Title":"Termonator Salvation","ReleaseDate":"\/Date(1224007200000)\/"}]</string>
```

Here is jQuery method in which I use Kendo Data Source

```
$(function () {
    alert("Welcome To Kendo");
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
                {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "/MovieService.asmx/Movies"
                           // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

                        }
                    },
                    change: function (e) {
                        alert(e);

                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert(e[2]);
                    },
                    pageSize: 10,
                    schema: {
                        data: "d"

                    }


                });

    $("#MovieGridView").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        height: 250,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "Title", title: "Movie Name" },
            { field: "ReleaseDate", title: "Movie Release" }
            ],
        editable: "popup",
        toolbar: ["create"]
    });
});
```

The above code show what I am doing in jQuery and when the error event call I got this error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

How can I convert the above data into JSON so I can use it in jQuery? And where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why are you using JSONP here? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: ok i remove jsonp but problem is still same plz solve it

Comment: i found another way of doing this by using WCF and JSONP its very cool combination and work perfectly

Comment: you need json with xml or only json

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify the [`ResponseFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.responseformat.aspx) of the method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetMovies() {
}
```

**Note:** For the sake of others who arrive at this question with similar issues, it's also important to note that you should being using `POST` requests, not `GET` requests. See: [JSON Hijacking and How ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 Avoids these Attacks](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx)

---

**EDIT**

Based on the jQuery that you posted, you're not calling the correct method. You C# defines a method called `GetMovies`, yet your jQuery is attempting to call a method called `Movies'.

This:

```
url: "/MovieService.asmx/Movies"
```

Should change to this:

```
url: "/MovieService.asmx/GetMovies"
```

Comment: @HaseebKhan, first of all, don't call me dear :-). Secondly, this is the proper way to return JSON formatted data. Please review my answer, and confirm that you've implemented it properly in your test environment.

Comment: see my updated question so its clear to you that what i am doing and where i going wrong! and sorry that i call u dear.

Comment: yes yes offcourse i remove the get and write this line also [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] but still my problem is not solved

Comment: but the problem is still same

Comment: @HaseebKhan, as you can tell by the upvotes, based on the info you've provided, this is the correct answer. Either provide more information, or take a second, or third, look at your code.

Comment: I have the same problem; it's bringing back xml-encapsulated json.