# My JSON is being wrapped in xml when returned by asmx web service?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, .net-3.5

Unfornately, the client only support VS 2008 (framework 3.5), not sure why my json is being wrapped in xml.  Using webforms.

My JSON returned:

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?><stringxmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[
    {
        "Name": "AAA",
        "Company": "AAAA",
        "Address": "AAAA",
        "Phone": "1204675",
        "Country": "US"
    },
    {
        "Name": "AAAA",
        "Company": "AAAA",
        "Address": "AAAA",
        "Phone": "AAA",
        "Country": "AAA"
    }
]</string>
```

My ASMX code:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class HCTCService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string TestJSON()
        {
            Employee[] e = new Employee[2];
            e[0] = new Employee();
            e[0].Name = "AAA";
            e[0].Company = "AAAA";
            e[0].Address = "AAAA";
            e[0].Phone = "1204675";
            e[0].Country = "US";
            e[1] = new Employee();
            e[1].Name = "AAAA";
            e[1].Company = "AAAA";
            e[1].Address = "AAAA";
            e[1].Phone = "AAA";
            e[1].Country = "AAA";
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088294/asp-net-asmx-web-service-returning-xml-instead-of-json

Comment: Did not have a solution to my prob.

Comment: maybe include your related web.config sections?