# Create basic webservice for JSON response in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I have created a example of webservice in ASP.NET. It is generating a response JSON formate but response is wrapping with XML  tag.
I don't want to XML and JSON mix output.

**ASP.NET Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

public WebService () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string TestJSON()
{
    Employee[] e = new Employee[2];

    e[0] = new Employee();
    e[0].Name = "Bhavesh";
    e[0].Company = "TCS";

    e[1] = new Employee();
    e[1].Name = "Jiten";
    e[1].Company = "Infosys";

    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(e);
 }
}

public class Employee
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Company { get; set; }
}
```

**Output :**

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
[{"Name":"Bhavesh","Company":"TCS"},{"Name":"Jiten","Company":"Infosys"}]
</string>
```

**Note:**
I do not want to use jQuery or any other like jQuery.
I need simple output in JSON.
**I'm using Visual Studio 2012**

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227624/asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-that-return-json-or-partial-html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088294/asp-net-asmx-web-service-returning-xml-instead-of-json/11120484

Comment: @bhavesh butani, you can chose one of the answers as "Accepted" answer if it solves your issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your config file. Probably [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11120484/1957479) can resolve your issue:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory"
                 verb="*" path="*.asmx"
                 type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                 resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```