# Asp.net web service return json

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I am using below code for my web service. I want return value in json. but this code return value in XML format only.

```
 [WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
 public bool login(string uname, string pwd)
 {  
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;
     if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
     {
         con.Open();
     }
     cmd.CommandText = "select * from UserList where UserName=@username and Password=@pwd";
     cmd.Connection = con;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = uname;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@pwd", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = pwd;

     SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     if (dr.Read() == true)
     {
         return true;
     }
     else
     {
         return false;
     }
     con.Close();
 }
```

Comment: Anything from `config` might be doing it?

Comment: `ResponseFormat.Json` is the default return type for  `ScriptMethod`. So unless you specify it shouldn't return `xml`. So let us see some part of your config(if any).May be something is wrong there.

Comment: following result shown

Comment: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<boolean xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">true</boolean>

Comment: i am changing the response format in .json but no change.

Comment: do you have any config's related?

Comment: yes i am using web config file.

Comment: <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="loginpage.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84358/discussion-between-gaurav-pal-and-amit-kumar-ghosh).

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088294/asp-net-asmx-web-service-returning-xml-instead-of-json . Does that help?