# Remove xml tag header from JSON response webService C#

Tags: c#, json, web-services

My problem is that I have a webservice on ASP.net, which returns a JSON string object (no XML). But when I call the webmethod I have this:

```
<string xmlns="https://www.puzzlebooks.com.ar">
{"Tipo":null,"Anio":0,"Mes":null,"CuentaContable":null,"Total":0,"OId":0}
</string>
```

On client side, the message error is this: `Unexpected token < in json at position 0`

I expected this JSON:

```
{"Tipo":null,"Anio":0,"Mes":null,"CuentaContable":null,"Total": 0,"OId": 0}
```

a pure JSON

This is my web service code:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json) ]
public string AcumuladoTotalCompraVenta_MesActual()
{
    try
    {
        ModeloDeClases.Dominio.EstadisticaCompraVenta totalAcumulado = null;
        totalAcumulado = RepositorioServicios.RepositoryServices.getInstance().getEstadisticasServices().CompraVenta_TotalAcumuladoDelMesActual(23);

        if (totalAcumulado == null)
            totalAcumulado = new ModeloDeClases.Dominio.EstadisticaCompraVenta();

        string queHAY = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(totalAcumulado);
        //  return totalAcumulado;   
        return queHAY;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.Error(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

And the code from client side (aspx page), is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () 
{  
    $.ajax
    ({  
        type: "POST",  
        dataType: "json",  
        contentType: "application/json",  
        url: "../webServices/wsEstadisticas.asmx/AcumuladoTotalCompraVenta_MesActual",
        data: "{}",  
        success: chartAcumuladoComprasVentas_MesActual,  

        error: function (request, status, error) 
        {
            alert('NOP!');
            alert(request.statusText);
            alert(error);
            alert(request.toString());
        }
    });  
})

function chartAcumuladoComprasVentas_MesActual()
{
    alert('IT S WORK!');
}
</script>
```

I search on this site about the same problems, but doesn't work. The library Newtonsoft for JSON don't work for me, because I get the same result when I didn't use it.

Comment: what's the content of totalAcumulado before serialization?

Comment: Note: This is only a fix but not the perfect solution. Can't you break your string to return only JSON part of it? Assuming your JSON remains same, you could do `queHAY = queHAY.subString(queHay.indexOf("{"), queHAY.indexOf("}")+1);`

Comment: Seems similar to this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088294/asp-net-asmx-web-service-returning-xml-instead-of-json

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone...I find my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088294/asp-net-asmx-web-service-returning-xml-instead-of-json: this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
this.Context.Response.Write(serial.Serialize(city));

Answer (score 1):

Thnaks a lot for everyone

I find my answer here: 
[asp.net asmx web service returning xml instead of json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088294/asp-net-asmx-web-service-returning-xml-instead-of-json)

```
this.Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
this.Context.Response.Write(serial.Serialize(city));
```