# WebService answer in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, webmethod

I am not expert of Internet communication protocols. Normally I develop some WebServices in c#, for my needs. My functions are developed with the [WebMethod] keyword and return numbers, for example two coordinates.
To call the WebService, for example with a browser, I write:

https://www.mysite.xx/MyWebService.asmx/MyWebMethod?Request=..Parameters ...

And I get an answer like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">-102866,667000005;-92718,2779999226</string>
```

Till to day, calling the WebService with programs, I process the above answer, to get what I need, i.e. just the two numbers. I would like to know whether it is possible to simply get an answer with the two numbers only, without the other stuff.

Comment: You might try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18684392 if you want to keep the asmx stuff.

Comment: Thanks. It resolved. As a matter of fact, my WebMethods were declared with return type (for example). Then they just returned their resulting numbers Instead I declared them as  "void" and simply used Context.Response.Write(.... numbers ..). Really trivial. Thanks again